# How to bypass user consent screen in DocuSign via API

Tags: docusignapi

This is in regards to DocuSign.

We will be using JWT OAuth approach for authentication in our project,currently for the first time, User Consent is required to  be provided before it generates the JWT token via code/API (see snapshot).
My question is can we bypass this first time user consent either in our code or some other technique so that the flow is smooth right from the first instance.
The link I referred is :https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9343.png)

Thanks in Advance.!
Atul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have Organization Administration enabled for your DocuSign account then you can proactively grant consent for some or all of the users in your account.

Talk with your DocuSign contact to try out Organization Administration.